# Show that as $n \to \infty, x^{n} \to \frac{x_1}{\|x_1\|}_{\infty}$ and $\|Ax^{n}\|_{\infty} \to \lambda_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let $A$ be an $N \times N$ matrix with $N$ linearly independent eigen vectors $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$ and corresponding eigen values $\lambda_i$, where $|\lambda_1| \gt |\lambda_2| \ge... \ge |\lambda_N|$. Let $$x^{o}=\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i x_i, \alpha_1 \ne 0$$ and $$x^{n}=\frac{A^nx^{0}}{\|A^nx^{0}\|_{\infty}}$$.  Show that as $n \to \infty, x^{n} \to \frac{x_1}{\|x_1\|}_{\infty}$ and $\|Ax^{n}\|_{\infty} \to \lambda_1$

Clearly $A^{n}x^{0}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_i\lambda_i^nx_i=\lambda_1^n\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i$. If I look at the term $$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i-\alpha_1x_1\right\|_{\infty} \le \sum_{i=2}^{N}|\alpha_i|\left\|\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right\|^{n}\|x_i\|_{\infty}$$ , then this goes to $0$ an $n \to \infty$. Hence $\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i \to \alpha_1x_1$  and since $\|.\|_{\infty}$ is continuous we have $\|\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i\|_{\infty} \to |\alpha_1\||x_1\|_{\infty}$. Hence $$-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i}{\left\|\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i\right\|_{\infty}}\le x^{n}=\frac{A^nx^{0}}{\|A^nx^{0}\|_{\infty}}=\frac{\lambda_1^n\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i}{|\lambda_1|^n\left\|\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i\right\|_{\infty}} \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i}{\left\|\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i\right\|_{\infty}} $$

I have no issues proving this if the eigen value with maximum modulus is positive. But it has to positive for the second part exactly means that. It is not mentioned in the question. 
Now how do I conclude from here?? I see that the limits have to be exactly the same but I am unable to prove so.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Consider as your vectorspace just $\mathbb R$ and $A=(-1)$, then $A^n x/\|A^n x\| = (-1)^n \text{sign}(x)$, which does not converge. If its important to you that the space not be on dimensional, consider $A= \begin{pmatrix}-1 &0 &0 &... \\0 &0 &0 &...\\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: If the maximum absolute value eigenvalue is a positive real number, then the statement is true though.

Comment: Why are you splitting this to the form $ -A_n \leq x^n \leq A_n$? Since you know $\alpha_1 \neq 0$, then $x^0 \neq 0$, and since $\lambda_1 \neq 0$, you know $x^n \neq 0$. So the infinity norm won't be zero, and you write the limit as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n}{lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n}$. You've already solved these limits. The only problem I guess is that as @s.harp implies if $\lambda_1$ and $\alpha_1$ have the same signs you have no problems, but if they have different signs then you'll get $- \frac{x}{||x||_{\infty}}$

Comment: @s.harp but it is not given to me that the maximum eigen value is a positive real no... But it has to be positive, How do I show that it is positive??

Comment: You cannot show that is positive, because it does not have to be positive... What you can do is show the statement is true only if the maximum eigenvalue is positive.

Comment: I am only proving the if part. . Right? ? It has to be mentioned in the question naa??

Comment: A possibility is that $\lambda_1=+1$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ and $x_1\ne 0\ne x_2$.. and $x^0=x_1+x_2$.Then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent and $x^n$ cannot converge to both $x_1/\|x_1\|$ and $x_2/\|x_2\|$.But we can switch by letting $\lambda^*_1=-1$,$\;\lambda^*_2=+1$,$\;x_1^*=x_2$,$\;x_2^*=x_1.$

Answer (score 0):

If maximum of all eigenvalues (in modulus) is zero, then the matrix is zero, and you don't have to do this procedure. Secondly, your iterative scheme appears to me as that of power method. In general power method iterations for eigenvector need not converge, but they get closer to aligning with the eigenspace. If the approximate eigenvector said are of uni norm (say, Euclidean norm), then the sequence will get closer to +/- of the eigenvector. Refer any numerical analysis book for power method.

Comment: This does not answer the question.